# Minimal size of vocabulary

Tags: vocabulary

What is the minimal size of vocabulary that could enable two persons to communicate more or less sensibly about matters of everyday life in English? Would 3000 words (8000 words, if different grammatical forms are taken into account) be a reasonable estimate?

Comment: The answer to the question "How long should my legs be?" is "Long enough to reach the ground". The answer to your question is "Big enough to give you the words you need to 'talk sensibly about matters of [your] everyday life in English'". Everyone will need a different vocabulary because everyone's everyday life differs. If you don't know the words to express your ideas, no matter how large your vocabulary is, it isn't big enough.

Comment: http://xkcd.com/1133/

Comment: the question is fine. voting to reopen.

Comment: Related:  [Are there acknowledged studies about the relationship of vocabulary and comprehension of English language?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/93289),   [Frequency of word use vs number of words](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/74704),  [Recent grammar additions](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/91871),

Comment: Voting to leave closed. Define "sensibly", define "everyday life", define "more or less". Voice of America is happy with 1514 words. Simple-English Wikipedia uses 2626. Swadesh makes do with around 200. The people who frequent our chat to actually communicate with one another, more or less sensibly, on a daily basis, took the test at [testyourvocab.com](http://testyourvocab.com/) and the results ranged between 14,400 and 42,300 words for native speakers, and between 25,000 and 34,400 words for non-native ones.

Answer (score 2):

Charles Ogdon reckoned it could be done with 850 words. See [here](http://ogden.basic-english.org/words.html)

Comment: When was that list put together? I notice that it includes **canvas** and **porter** (words I doubt I use or hear from one month to the next), but not **plastic** or **call**, for example.

Comment: @FumbleFingers 1930. Also the Ogdon word list is 850 but the grammar rules allow for compounding so arguably the total vocabulary might be much bigger than 850.

Comment: @FumbleFingers. Ogdon lived from 1889 to 1957, so, yes, he would have included words little used today, and missed those that we do use frequently. That’s just one of the hazards of trying to answer a question like this. The vocabulary list was just one of the elements of Basic English, which he devised as possible international language.

Comment: @Barrie: I guess. It still seems rather odd that he should have thought *canvas* and *porter* were necessary in such a restricted vocabulary. I don't suppose he was a painter with a drink problem!

Answer (score 0):

[This link here](http://www.fltr.ucl.ac.be/fltr/germ/etan/bibs/vocab/cup.html) gives some interesting figures on words needed for comprehension and coverage. It's mostly related to written text, but it does give a nice comparison of "regular" reading versus something like a teen novel, and about 1/3 of the way down the page it suggests a vocabulary of ~ 2,000-3,000.

It also gives breakdowns for newspapers, texts, novels, etc.